# Remove and delete pointers that match a condition in a vector

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a `std::vector` that I would like to remove pointers from the vector that meet the condition `isDestroyed()`, but also call delete on the pointers.

I did the following, but it requires looping over the vector twice. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
std::vector<GameObject*> destroyedObjects;
// Get objects to be deleted
std::copy_if (gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), std::back_inserter(destroyedObjects), [](GameObject* b){return b->isDestroyed();} );
// Remove objects from vector
gameObjects.erase(
    std::remove_if(
            gameObjects.begin(),
            gameObjects.end(),
            [](GameObject* p) { return p->isDestroyed(); }
    ),
    gameObjects.end()
);
// Delete the objects
for (GameObject* o : destroyedObjects)
    delete o;
```

Comment: Loop in the opposite direction so you can remove an element without the other iterators being moved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` does the deletion for free:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;

// Remove objects from vector
gameObjects.erase(
    std::remove_if(
            gameObjects.begin(),
            gameObjects.end(),
            [](const auto& p) { return p->isDestroyed(); }
    ),
    gameObjects.end()
);
```

I suggest to use it instead. It also avoids mistakes like forgetting to delete or double deleting.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
auto end = std::stable_partition(
            gameObjects.begin(),
            gameObjects.end(),
            [](GameObject* p) { !return p->isDestroyed(); }
    );
for (auto i = end; i < gameObjects.end(); i++) {
    delete *i;
}
gameObjects.erase(end, gameObjects.end());
```

Comment: [What does this code do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/1705337)

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work as `remove_if` leaves the values in the removed part of the range unspecified. They are not required to (and in my experience won't) be one to one the same values that were removed.

Comment: @Kyle, you're right (I've never used `remove_if` for anything other than erasing), `stable_partition` should do the job

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 vectors. The iterator returned by `std::remove_if()` can be used to know which objects need to be `delete`'d:

```cpp
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
...
auto newEnd = std::remove_if(
    gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(),
    [](GameObject* p) { return p->isDestroyed(); }
);
for(auto iter = newEnd; iter != gameObjects.end(); ++iter) {
    delete *iter;
}
gameObjects.erase(newEnd, gameObjects.end());
```

If you change your vector to hold `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>` instead of `GameObject*`, you don't need to `delete` the objects manually anymore:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;
...
gameObjects.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(),
        [](std::unique_ptr<GameObject> &p) { return p->isDestroyed(); }
    ),
    gameObjects.end()
);
```

Comment: @walnut it doesn't really matter in this case

Comment: You can't use the values between the iterator returned by `remove_if` and the end as the values in that part of the range are unspecified, so deleting them can lead to UB. Using `unique_ptr` is fine in this case and will do the correct thing. If you want an implementation that can safely delete the removed pointers before erasing you need to use `std::partition` instead.